# Guardar solo un valor de checkbox con dos valores

Tags: php, html, laravel, checkbox

Tengo un grupo de checkbox, y quiero que solo se guarde un valor de los checkbox cuando este seleccionado

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="hidden"  name="profession[]"  value="PintorNO">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="profession[]"  value="PintorSI">

<input class="form-check-input" type="hidden" name="profession[]" value="EscultornoNO">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="profession[]" value="EscultorSI">
```

Cuando no selecciono ninguno, se guarda el valor por defecto, pero cuando selecciono Pintor(por ejemplo) se guardan ambos values 'PintorNo' y 'PintorSI', solo necesito que se guarde un valor, este checado o no

alguna idea?GRACIAS :D

Comment: Hola, como lo estas seleccionando? Si quieres obtener el valor de cada uno individualmente, te sugiero colocarles un ID a cada input

Comment: Solo son 2 checkbox, cada uno tiene un tipo 'hidden' y cuando No esta seleccionado el checkbox se envia el valor del hidden y cuando Si esta seleccionado se envia el 'normal' que tiene como tipo 'checkbox' ,

Comment: No entiendo para que tiene un hidden, si los datos son estáticos, puedes hacer una condicion para que tomes el valor que quieras si el checkbox esta seleccionado o no

Comment: como puedo hacer esa condicion?

Comment: En cualquier caso, el valor de un input checkbox retorna un booleano, así que con eso puedes hacer la condición, si es verdadero que el valor sea "PintorSi", si es falso que el valor sea "PintorNo"

Comment: GRACIAS :D lo hare asi

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#verificar").click(function(){
const activo = $("#activo").prop('checked');
console.log(activo)
});

/*
y en tu controlador de laravel haces lo siguiente
    if ($request->activo == 'true') {
        $pintor = "SI";
    }else if($request->activo == 'false'){
          $pintor = "NO";
    }
    */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="activo">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="activo">Activo</label>
  </div>
  <button id="verificar">Verificar</button>
```

Hola, lo mejor es hacer lo con js, utiliza la libreria de boostrap, esta un componente que se llama switch, te dejo el empleo, lo envias al controlador de laravel con ajax, el valor que te devuelve es true o false. Espero que te sirva